# Flask routes not updating

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, routes, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to bootstrap a basic flask setup but after managing to setup the db connection and running the server, the routes are not being updated but seem to be cached to the original route I added in the very beginning (Which now doesn't even exist).

Below is the relevant code.

launch.py (python file pointed at by FLASK_APP)

```
from app import app,db
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand


#Model Creation

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "Hello World!!"


@app.route("/test", methods=['GET'])
def test():
    return "Test"
```

Note that with or without the given routes the only route that works is the / one and returns "Hello World!" which was the original string, but now the routes aren't being updated.

Could anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone encounters a similar issue I found a remnant flask.exe process still running from an earlier run that was not properly terminated and hence was still providing the routes itself. Therefore the solution is to terminate that process manually. Going to leave this open maybe someone encounters same issue